# iOS app memory leaks after doing Analyze in Xcode 4.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, xcode4.5

I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 to practice iOS programming. My app seems to compile just fine, but when I do Product -> Analyze I get the following messages that are better illustrated in a

[image]

I'd appreciate if someone could explain this to me?

PS. I kinda understand what most that does, except the word `__bridge` which was suggested by a compiler and I agreed to add it.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for adding the image. It said I can't do it because of reputation or something???

Comment: Yep. Precisely. They want to make sure you're a reputable character before they let you post images. Allegedly that's to prevent spammers from posting unwanted images. You need to prove yourself to the community before being given permission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `__bridge_transfer`, not `__bridge`. You want to transfer ownership to ARC, so it will clean it up for you. Failure to do that will result in a leak.

See the discussion of [toll-free bridging](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1) in the *Transitioning to ARC Release Notes*.

Per the WWDC 2012 notes, Apple actually suggests `CFBridgingRelease`. Thus:

```
NSString *encodedString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just from the curiosity, where can I learn about all those new additions: `__bringe`, `__weak`, etc?

Comment: That document I reference, [Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW1) talks about it. Also see the [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

It is not a leak as far as you carefully track it and release in right moment. Analyser just makes a hint that function should either return autoreleased ref if someone needs it outside or release it inside the function.

Comment: I guess I haven't done objective-C coding for awhile, because I did try to `autorelease` it  but it marked it as an error, saying that APC or something doesn't like it...

Comment: You should not return a +1 object from a method whose name does not start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` at the start of the name. This does constitute a leak.

Comment: wolfrevokcats, your project may be ARC configured. If so.. what I said is not quite right ;) I don't like ARC, release things myself.

Comment: To be honest with you, yes, this ARC does confuse me, but if you think about it, if it takes care of releasing all allocated memory (like C# does) -- that would be nice. Although, I'm not sure how much slower the resulting code would be -- hope not as bad as C# stuff? For a regular app that would not be an issue. But it may, for an intensive game for instance...

Comment: @wolfrevokcats While I'm sympathetic to Umka's point, I have to say that I think it's nuts to not use ARC. I've never heard of observable negative performance impact, and it dramatically reduces the amount of code we write and test code for routine memory management.

Comment: @Rob: Yes, I agree. It dramatically simplifies development. And whatever impact this may impose on performance, you'd win in the amount of memory leaks it will prevent. My only negative encounter with memory autorelease mechanism comes from ActionScript programming (that is Flash) which made it an unbearably slow resource hog for larger projects...

Comment: I tried ARC once, seems about 1y ago when it was only introduced and it caused more issues with memory consumption than it solved introducing subst. amount of simplicity. Either it was buggy or it just provoked me to use it wrong way and rely on it too much. This btw means that one should learn how to use arc in a pretty much the same way as not to use it :)

Comment: Still... using autorelease a lot is somewhat similar to ARC in meaning that they both defer actual memory release to some later period. autorelease pools (I think) do it in main thread when all current events in all active run loops are handled. Anyways, for quite some time there will be a lot of potentially not used memory busy in autorelease pools. So I'm trying not to use it much as well :)

Comment: @Umka ARC is rock solid and not a performance issue. I understand what you're trying to say about `autorelease` (though I don't think you're quite right on the specifics). It's quite easy to force `dealloc` to take place promptly. Using ARC is _not_ just like using `autorelease`. It depends upon how you use it.

Comment: @Rob I understand it. It was kind of analogy, not quite good may be